# Calculating DFFITS using the rms package manually

Tags: r, regression, logistic, repeated-measures

my data:

```
> mydat
    X Y
 1.74 0
 1.90 0
 1.91 0
 1.97 1
 2.02 1
 2.27 0
 2.32 1
 2.39 0
 2.42 0
 3.07 0


lr2 = lrm(Y~X,data=mydat,x=TRUE,y=TRUE)
```

Running the `residuals` command as follows gives me values my calculations agree with:
`residuals(lr2,type=’hat’)`
`residuals(lr2,type=’dffit’)`

the `hat` values agree with `influence measures`. I've figured out that the DFFIT values are given by [X(βˆ◦−β˜(k)
)]k

Instead of what I'm used to, where x̃ is used instead of x. But, I'm unsure how they achieve the calculation of
`residuals(lr2,type=’dffits’)`
Which formula are they using? I am unable to find it in the documentation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone happens to stumble upon this in the future, after some digging in the source code I've found the answer:
`(infl$hat^.5)*g$residuals/(infl$sigma * (1 - infl$hat)) ))` 
is the calculation, where:
`L` is the linear.predictors parameter of the object, where the object here is  lr2 of type lrm.
`P` is defined as the cumulative probability of `L`
then we have `v = P*(1-P)`
define `g` as
`g <- lm(L + (Y - P) / v ~ X, weights=v)`
finally,
`infl <- lm.influences(g)`